# in which database need to restore database of biometric system Safescan TA-8025Clocking In System?

Tags: sql-server, database, biometrics

Biometric system Safescan TA-8025Clocking In System gives .bak file. I was trying to restore the same on `MS SQLserver 2008 R2` but it is giving error:

> "The media file on device "drive:\path\filename.bak" is incorrectly formed, SQL server can not process this media file."

Can any one please help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the answer... You can restore your database using firebird.

This is a best solution for any `.bak` or `.fdb` file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're .bak is corrupt. Maybe with downloading/copying it? Can you give this a try and send the output of this command.

```
RESTORE HEADERONLY 
FROM DISK = N'C:\AdventureWorks-FullBackup.bak' 
WITH NOUNLOAD, CONTINUE_AFTER_ERROR ;
```

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your valuable feedback... I have tried the way you mentioned but still getting an error as follows:

"Msg 3241, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
The media family on device 'D:\backup.bak' is incorrectly formed. SQL Server cannot process this media family.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
RESTORE HEADERONLY is terminating abnormally."

Comment: So this file seems to be corrupt. Maybe you can copy the file again from source and check MD5 hash on source and destination?

Comment: I have tried for another back up file created by same software... But still stuck on the same error.. :(

Comment: By which sofware this backup is created? Can't you just create a SQL Server backup via SSMS? BACKUP [DATABASE] TO DISK = '' ;?

Comment: It is automated backup from the Safescan TA-8025 Clocking In System.

Comment: No experience with that, but I really should be worried about my backups now ....